# how to use one model in two views

Tags: qml

i have one model for pictures and want to show them in grid view or list view (fullscreen) synchronously. if user clicks on one image in grid view i want this image to be shown in fullscreen mode (in listview).

i have one solution but my list view scrolls till "the current index".

THanx.

**PhotoView.qml**

```
Rectangle {
    width: settings.pageWidth
    height: settings.pageHeight
    anchors.fill: parent

    VisualDataModel {
        id: visualModel
        delegate: PhotoDelegate {}
        model: photosModel
    }


    ListView {
        id:fullscreen
        anchors.fill: parent;
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem;
        flickDeceleration: 500
        //highlightFollowsCurrentItem: true
        highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
        preferredHighlightBegin: 0; preferredHighlightEnd: 0
        cacheBuffer: width;
        spacing:  settings.largeMargin
        model: visualModel.parts.grid

    }

    GridView{
        id:grid
         width: settings.pageWidth
         height: settings.pageHeight
         anchors.fill: parent
         cellWidth: settings.gridCellWidth
         cellHeight: settings.gridCellHeight
         snapMode: GridView.SnapToRow
         cacheBuffer: settings.pageHeight
         clip: true
         model: visualModel.parts.grid
    }

//    // Menu/Back Button
//    IconButton{
//        id: backButton
//        iconSource: "qrc:///gfx/back_arrow.png"
//        anchors.right: parent.right
//        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
//        onClicked: mainWindow.close();
//    }

    //  Fade Top
    Image{
        id:bottom_fade
        source:  "qrc:///gfx/bottom-page-fade.png"
        height: 33
        width: settings.pageWidth
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.left:   parent.left
        anchors.right:  parent.right

    }
    //  Fade Bottom
    Image{
        id:top_fade
        source:  "qrc:///gfx/top-page-fade.png"
        height: 33
        width: settings.pageWidth
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left:   parent.left
        anchors.right:  parent.right

    }

}
```

**PhotoDelegate.qml**

```
import QtQuick 1.0
import Qt 4.7
import "../views"
import "../model"
import "../views/components"

Package {
    Item { id: listDelegate; Package.name: 'list'; width: settings.pageWidth; height: settings.pageHeight }
    Item { id: gridDelegate;  Package.name: 'grid'; width: settings.pageWidth; height: settings.pageHeight }

    Item {
        id: wrapper
        width: settings.pageWidth; height: settings.pageHeight

        Image {
            id: thumbnail; smooth: true; source: thumbnail_url

        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                if (wrapper.state == 'inGrid') {
                    listDelegate.fullscreen.view.currentIndex = index;
                    wrapper.state = 'fullscreen'
                } else {
                    gridDelegate.grid.view.currentIndex = index;
                    wrapper.state = 'inGrid'
                }
            }

        }

        state: 'inGrid'
        states: [
            State {
                name: 'fullscreen'
                ParentChange { target: wrapper; parent: listDelegate; x: 0; y: 0;
                width: listDelegate.width; height: listDelegate.height
                }
            },
            State {
                name: 'inGrid'
                ParentChange {
                    target: wrapper; parent: gridDelegate
                    x: 0; y: 0; width: gridDelegate.width; height: gridDelegate.height
                }
            }
        ]

        transitions: [
            Transition {
                from: 'inGrid'; to: 'fullscreen'
                SequentialAnimation {
                    PauseAnimation { duration: gridItem.GridView.isCurrentItem ? 0 : 600 }
                    ParentAnimation {
                        target: wrapper; via: foreground
                        NumberAnimation {
                            targets: [ wrapper]
                            properties: 'x,y,width,height,opacity'
                            duration: gridItem.GridView.isCurrentItem ? 600 : 1; easing.type: 'OutQuart'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            Transition {
                from: 'fullscreen'; to: 'inGrid'
                ParentAnimation {
                    target: wrapper; via: foreground
                    NumberAnimation {
                        targets: [ wrapper ]
                        properties: 'x,y,width,height,opacity'
                        duration: gridItem.GridView.isCurrentItem ? 600 : 1; easing.type: 'OutQuart'
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: The question isn't clear. So you are able to do what you want but you don't want the list to scroll before it displays the picture ?

Comment: yes, exactly. But I have the solution now, and it is just to use  onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            thumbnailView.positionViewAtIndex(currentIndex, GridView.Contain)
        }

Comment: I have a similar problemMy problem is that when I switch from the Gridview to the listview only the clicked image appears and if I scroll the listview the other images don't appear at all,while there place is reserved which means if I scroll twice to the left then scroll back two times to the right the original photo(Which appeared when clicked) appears again. And if the listview is the default view when the application runs it works fine, but also when I click any image in order to switch to the gridview only the clicked image appears in the gridview and it appears in its exact place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To showing selected item without scrolling until index of selected item is to synchronize the view elements current index:

onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            your_component.positionViewAtIndex(currentIndex, YourViewElement.Contain)
        }

Comment: I have a similar problemMy problem is that when I switch from the Gridview to the listview only the clicked image appears and if I scroll the listview the other images don't appear at all,while there place is reserved which means if I scroll twice to the left then scroll back two times to the right the original photo(Which appeared when clicked) appears again.
And if the listview is the default view when the application runs it works fine, but also when 
I click any image in order to switch to the gridview only the clicked image appears in the gridview and it appears in its exact place!