# How to use package in QML with two views?

Tags: qml

I have a similar problem like the one in this [***this***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100720/how-to-use-one-model-in-two-views) question
But mine is a little different. My problem is that when I switch from the Gridview to the listview only the clicked image appears and if I scroll the listview the other images don't appear at all while there place is reserved which means if I scroll twice to the left then scroll back two times to the right the original photo(Which appeared when clicked) appears again. And if the listview is the default view when the application runs it works fine, but also when I click any image in order to switch to the gridview only the clicked image appears in the gridview and it appears in its exact place! Any Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it, I adapted the Photo viewer Example that is provided by Qt and it works just fine now.